# MSBuild File to Run Code Analysis Without Overlap

Tags: .net, msbuild, continuous-integration

I am creating an MSBuild file to combine some tasks of the things I need to do on my build server into one step. Part of this process requires running code analysis. My problem is that I have running code analysis for multiple top level projects but they each have the same dependencies on other projects like our Utility Library. This means that each run of code analysis duplicates a code analysis run of the Utility Library. Here is my MSBuild file:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Dev</Configuration>
        <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
        <RunCodeAnalysis>true</RunCodeAnalysis>
        <CodeAnalysisTargets>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\CodeAnalysis\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.targets</CodeAnalysisTargets>
        <CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors>true</CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors>
        <StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings>false</StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings>
        <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG;CODE_ANALYSIS</DefineConstants>
        <BuildInParallel>true</BuildInParallel>
        <WebProjectTargets>Clean;Build;Package</WebProjectTargets>
        <OtherProjectTargets>Clean;Build</OtherProjectTargets>
        <GenerateSerializationAssemblies>Off</GenerateSerializationAssemblies>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="Build">
        <!-- Web Projects -->
        <MSBuild
            Projects="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Source\WebProjects\WebApp1\WebApp1.csproj"
            Properties="
                Configuration=$(Configuration);
                PackageLocation=$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Packages\WebApp1.zip;
                RunCodeAnalysis=$(RunCodeAnalysis);
                CodeAnalysisTargets=$(CodeAnalysisTargets);
                CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors=$(CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors);
                StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings=$(StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings);
                DefineConstants=$(DefineConstants);
                BuildInParallel=$(BuildInParallel);
                GenerateSerializationAssemblies=$(GenerateSerializationAssemblies);
                "
            Targets="$(WebProjectTargets)" />
        <MSBuild
            Projects="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Source\WebProjects\WebApp2\WebApp2.csproj"
            Properties="
                Configuration=$(Configuration);
                PackageLocation=$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Packages\WebApp2.zip;
                RunCodeAnalysis=$(RunCodeAnalysis);
                CodeAnalysisTargets=$(CodeAnalysisTargets);
                CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors=$(CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors);
                StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings=$(StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings);
                DefineConstants=$(DefineConstants);
                BuildInParallel=$(BuildInParallel);
                GenerateSerializationAssemblies=$(GenerateSerializationAssemblies);
                "
            Targets="$(WebProjectTargets)" />
        <MSBuild
            Projects="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Source\WebProjects\Administrator\Administrator.csproj"
            Properties="
                Configuration=$(Configuration);
                PackageLocation=$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Packages\Administrator.zip;
                RunCodeAnalysis=$(RunCodeAnalysis);
                CodeAnalysisTargets=$(CodeAnalysisTargets);
                CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors=$(CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors);
                StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings=$(StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings);
                DefineConstants=$(DefineConstants);
                BuildInParallel=$(BuildInParallel);
                GenerateSerializationAssemblies=$(GenerateSerializationAssemblies);
                "
            Targets="$(WebProjectTargets)" />
        <MSBuild
            Projects="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Source\OtherProjects\Service\Service.csproj"
            Properties="
                Configuration=$(Configuration);
                RunCodeAnalysis=$(RunCodeAnalysis);
                CodeAnalysisTargets=$(CodeAnalysisTargets);
                CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors=$(CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors);
                StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings=$(StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings);
                DefineConstants=$(DefineConstants);
                BuildInParallel=$(BuildInParallel);
                GenerateSerializationAssemblies=$(GenerateSerializationAssemblies);
                "
            Targets="$(OtherProjectTargets)" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Any idea as to how to prevent code analysis from running on the same assembly more than once in this situation?

Comment: Do you really need to run the code analysis every time you do a build? I usually run it on built binaries as it will really slow the build down and i doubt it needs to run any more frequently than daily.

Comment: I run code analysis every time dev builds (every two hours if there are changes to the code) as we want to be notified when we need to correct our code. If I change this I would modify my setup so I have one plan to run code analysis every hour and one to build dev every two hours.

Comment: Can you run the build with /v:diag and hunt down this line: `Target "RunCodeAnalysis:` it should show on the next couple of lines what the Input and what the Output was. If you clean out the build folder you might keep the `*.lastcodeanalysissucceeded` laying around because they determine if the target is out-of-date.

Comment: Could you not combine all the projects into a single solution and then call that solution from msbuild? Then could run the code analysis at the solution level maybe?

Comment: I agree with @rene: when you run Clean target you delete results of code analysis of already built and analyzed target. Divide build on two parts: first will clean up everything and second will run build with code  analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, I run code analysis command line tool, after "packing" my binary distribution. The [MSBuildCodeMetrics](https://github.com/ericlemes/MSBuildCodeMetrics) is an "embryo" project for running metrics inside build.

The idea is to break the build if some user commits a method with too many lines or with too many cyclomatic complexity, but the project isn't with this maturity yet.

Anyway, if you want to run the metrics through command line, try:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385914.aspx

Of course you'll need some magic to copy all the assemblies to a temp dir (like your final package) and then run the metrics based on this directory.